# Is it possible to save Sound in Local Storage - Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I need a function that saves sound from APIs in Local Storage to play it later with the audio player plugin in Flutter. Has anyone tried to do something like this?

Comment: You can follow this link: https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files

Comment: I think it doesn't help very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you getting the sound from? A URL? Assuming this, copy from the URL to a temporary file, then pass the uri of that temporary file to audio player.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future<Uri> fetchAudio(String url, String filename) async {
  Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  String tempPath = tempDir.path;
  File tempFile = File('$tempPath/$filename');

  http.Response response = await http.get(url);
  // todo - check status
  await tempFile.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes, flush: true);

  return tempFile.uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

import 'package:flutter_sound/flutter_sound.dart';

```
Future record() async {
  final recorder = FlutterSoundRecorder();
  final getApplicationPath = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  final folderPath = await _getFolderPath(getApplicationPath, 'audio');

  try {
    var filePath = '$folderPath/${generateUuid()}.wav'; // Use WAV instead of MP3
    await recorder.startRecorder(toFile: filePath, codec: Codec.pcm16WAV);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}

Future stop() async {
  await recorder.stopRecorder() ?? '';
}

_getFolderPath(Directory directory, String folderId) async {
  final folder = Directory(directory.path + "/" + folderId);
  if (!(await folder.exists())) {
    folder.create();
    return folder.path;
  }
  return folder.path;
}
```

//The above code will work to record audio in internal directory.Here I have used flutter_sound: ^9.2.13 package.